# Azure AD B2C SAML authentication in React

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the react sample app provided by azure to test Custom policy authentication

It works fine for the basic JWT Sign in Policy.
Now I have configured the custom policy for SAML using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

I have changed the policy and clientId in the authConfig.js in the react app but now it shows an error screen on authentication popup screen-

this is the current config

```
auth: {
        clientId: 'xxxxxx-9cc3-xxxxxx-a028-xxxxxxxx',
        authority: 'https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/mloflocrm.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN_SAML2/samlp/metadata',
        knownAuthorities: ["xxxxx.b2clogin.com"],
        redirectUri: '/',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: '/', 
    },
```

[image: azure ad b2c login screen]

Is there any configuration I am missing?
note- the login screen works fine when I test it on
https://samltestapp2.azurewebsites.net/SP

Comment: This really requires debugging unfortunately, your best bet is to ensure B2C is connected to App Insights and look through the logs it generates to find out what the actual error was. Though I would say that I don't think React (or any SPA) will support SAML as there's inherently a server interaction required. You have to do things like have your app expose metadata, configure certificates, and support a SAML response being sent via POST.

Comment: Thanks, is there any document that I can follow for SAML authentication through nodejs server? I did not find any.

Comment: I tried to find but other than the SAML setup on Azure AD B2C, I found nothinng

Comment: [node-saml](https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml) seems to be the library to use. I've not used it personally (I work in .NET rather than nodejs) but on the face of it it looks like I'd expect a SAML SP library to look.